# Use `jest.spyOn` on an exported function from a Node module

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs, spy

In [Jest](https://jestjs.io), to spy (and optionally mock the implementation) on a method, we do the following:

```js
const childProcess = require('child_process');
const spySpawnSync = jest.spyOn(childProcess, 'spawnSync').mockImplementation();
```

This allows us to use `spySpawnSync` to check what arguments it was last called with, like so:

```js
expect(spySpawnSync).lastCalledWith('ls');
```

However, this is not possible with Node modules that export a function, such as with the [execa](https://www.npmjs.com/package/execa) package.

I tried each the following, but none of them spy or mock the function:

```js
// Error: `Cannot spy the undefined property because it is not a function; undefined given instead`
jest.spyOn(execa);

// Error: `Cannot spyOn on a primitive value; string given`
jest.spyOn('execa');

// Error: If using `global.execa = require('execa')`, then does nothing. Otherwise, `Cannot spy the execa property because it is not a function; undefined given instead`.
jest.spyOn(global, 'execa');
```

Therefore, is there any way to spy on modules that export a function, such as `execa` in the given example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the exact same need and problem with `execa`, and here's how I made it work:

```js
import execa from 'execa'


jest.mock('execa', () => jest.fn())

test('it calls execa', () => {
  runSomething()
  expect(execa).toHaveBeenCalled()
})
```

So basically, since the imported module is the function itself, what you do is mock the whole module with `jest.mock`, and simply return a Jest mock function as its replacement.

Since `jest.fn()` is what `jest.spyOn()` relies on under the hood, you benefit from the same assertion methods in your tests :)

Comment: @oliver-lance, I like your answer. It works for my use case when I just want to verify that the module function has been called. 

However, I was trying to mock the response for each call to `execa`, when testing a user defined function that calls it multiple times and takes different paths based on the response of say the second call.  This seems to be difficult. I'm trying to determine how best to proceed.  

I'm thinking of creating a class with methods that wrap each type of call, based on parameters.  It's relatively easy to mock each method of the class.

Comment: Could you maybe use a mock implementation for `execa` instead of the empty mock function I used? Like this: `jest.fn(cmd => doSomething())` You would of course have a more complex body, but at least you can control the return value of your mock function depending on the executable path

Answer (score 0):

We can try mocking the module at the start of the test itself, say before the `describe` block, like below:

```
jest.mock('execa’, () => ({
  Method1: jest.fn(),
  Method2: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(…some mock value to be returned)
}));
```

here `Method1` and `Method2` are some methods of execa which you would like to mock and test, or if you are consuming them.

Else, you can just mock like below and it should work:

```
jest.mock('execa');
```